# SetAsign PDF Parser - File is Encrypted

Tags: php, pdf, encryption, fpdf

I am using the SetAsign PDF parser which can be found at the following link

https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/manual/#p-266

However, when using the setSourceFile() function to get the path of a file, I am getting the following error for one of the PDF files

> File is Encrypted!

However, I can view the file without having to provide a password i.e. it does not appear to actually be encrypted.

Is there some other form of encryption for PDFs I need to be aware of? Is there a way of decrypting this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[FPDI cannot handle encrypted PDF files.](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-fpdi-import-encrypted-pdf-documents/#question-87)

A PDF document can also be encrypted if you don't need a password to open it. In that case it is simply encrypted with an empty user password. A decryption process is still needed, which is not implemented in FPDI.